# A question about false discovery rate usage

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I read related answers here but did not help.
I am correlating two sets of features (time series) and for each given feature in the set A, I want to see which of the 9 features in the set B correlates significantly to it. The set A consists of 10 features and the set B - of 9. I want to adjust p values for Pearson correlations using Benjamini-Hohberg procedure, but there are two ways to apply it:

1) apply to 9x10 correlation matrix, which means that the whole problem considered one test consisting of 90 correlations between teh set A and the set B

2) to see the problem as 10 separate tests and adjust p values for each test (i.e. column of the matrix) separately

I don't know which way would be correct. 1) makes sense because the both sets of features are extracted from the same data and there exist some correlations within each set. So within each set features are not statistically independent. 2) makes sense because I am trying to interpret each feature in A  'independently' from each other.

Any advise would be appreciated.